# Chaining multiple filters if condition exist

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to chain two filters, based in two ranges (arrays) of params that may also be empty, so it would be possible that f.ex. `speedlimit=[]`

```
var speedfilter =[240,300]
var pricefilter = [80,120]
var cars = [
  {name:'Ferrari', maxspeed:240, price: 100},
  {name:'Porsche', maxspeed:220, price: 90},
  {name:'Bugatti', maxspeed:300, price: 500}
  ];


if (speedfilters) {
  return cars.filter(function (car) {
    return car.maxspeed >= speedfilter[0] && car.maxspeed <= speedfilter[1];
  })
} else if (pricefilter) {
  return cars.filter(function (car) {
    return car.price >= pricefilter[0] && car.price <= pricefilter[1];
  })
}
else return cars
```

The result in the example above should output `{name:'Ferrari', speed:240, price: 100}`

What would be the way to do it with javascript `filter`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it possible that there is a minimum speed but no maximum speed?

Comment: Dont use else if, filter cars by speed limit first and assign to a variable, then filter that variable by price limit

Comment: Maybe the names were confusing, I just changed it. I just want to filter the objects whose maxspeed are within the first range, and then filter the output again with the price

Comment: I'm confused by `speedlimit=''` - that variable is nowhere in your code. Did you mean `speedfilter=[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `filterCar` method via prototype inheritance

```
Array.prototype.filterCar = function(feature, range) {
   return this.filter((el) => {
     // is the range defined?
     if (!!range.length) {
        return el[feature] >= range[0] && el[feature] <= range[1];
     }
     else {
        return true;
     }
   })
};


var cars = [
  {name:'Ferrari', speed:240, price: 100},
  {name:'Porsche', speed:220, price: 90},
  {name:'Bugatti', speed:300, price: 500}
 ];

var result1 = cars.filterCar('speed', [240, 300])
                  .filterCar('price', [80, 120]));

var result2 = cars.filterCar('speed', [ ])
                  .filterCar('price', [80, 120]));



console.log(result1); // [{name: "Ferrari", speed: 240, price: 100}]

console.log(result2); /* [{name: "Ferrari", speed: 240, price: 100}, 
                         {name: "Porsche", speed: 220, price: 90}] */
```

Comment: `filterCar` on the prototype of `Array`.... doesn't quite feel "right". Could/should have just been a method call. Also doesnt cover the "if exists" requirement.

Comment: this is just an example about how to use `filter` function. Don't understand the downvote btw.

Comment: Wasnt mine! I promise.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but isn't the main thrust of the question how to handle possibly empty ranges?

Comment: Yep, @MarkMeyer is correct, while this solves it when you know there is an array, it doesn't solve if you don't know in advance if the array will be empty or not. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Joe82 it now does via the `if...else` inside the filter BTW

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your filtering up into a re-usable method, and this can account for the filter not being available.

```
function filterCars(carsArray, property, rangeArray) {
   // if rangeArray is not supplied, or is empty, just return the unfiltered input
   if(!rangeArray|| rangeArray.length === 0) {
      return carsArray;
   }
   // otherwise filter according to logic
   return carsArray.filter(car => car[property] >= rangeArray[0] && car[property] <= rangeArray[1]);
}
```

This can be chained, or for more readability called in sequence:

```js
 function filterCars(carsArray, property, rangeArray) {      
   if(!rangeArray|| rangeArray.length === 0) {
      return carsArray;
   }
   return carsArray.filter(car => car[property] >= rangeArray[0] && car[property] <= rangeArray[1]);
}

var speedfilter = []; // [240,300]
var pricefilter = [80,120]
var cars = [
  {name:'Ferrari', maxspeed:240, price: 100},
  {name:'Porsche', maxspeed:220, price: 90},
  {name:'Bugatti', maxspeed:300, price: 500}
];

cars = filterCars(cars,"maxspeed",speedfilter);
cars = filterCars(cars,"price",pricefilter);

console.log(cars);
```